# .each parse JSON returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hi I have the following codes:

```
$.ajax({'type':'POST', 'url':'https://www.123.com/site/gethistory',
        'data':{'a': this.username, 'b': username},
        'success':function(history){
            alert(history);
            var codes = jQuery.parseJSON(history);
            $.each(codes, function(key, value) {
                alert(key);
            }); //each
        }, 
        'error':function(){
        }
       });  //ajax
```

Right now the key is undefined. And i tried to alert(value.text), it still gives me undefined.

---

history is alerted as this:

> [{"demo":{"text":"hi
>   man","time":"1380167419"},"admin":{"text":"hi","time":"1380167435"},"demo":{"text":"this
>   works flawless now.","time":"1380167436"},"demo":{"text":"we are
>   basically done with this/","time":"1380167443"}}]

Comment: Did you open the console and check if parseJSON is throwing an error ?

Comment: @adeneo No there is not error.

Comment: That URL is just some random URL you picked, right, you're not trying to do a cross domain request ?

Comment: @adeneo yeah that's random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfThb/). However, there is a problem with your JSON.

Although it is syntactically correct, it is structured such that you are returning an array of one object with a number of properties all with the same name:

```
[
  { "demo":{
      "text":"hi man",
      "time":"1380167419"
    },
    "admin":{
      "text":"hi",
      "time":"1380167435"
    },
    "demo":{
       "text":"this works flawless now.",
       "time":"1380167436"
    },
    "demo":{
      "text":"we are basically done with this/",
      "time":"1380167443"
    }
  }
]
```

Each successive `demo` will overwrite the previous one, so you'll only see the last `demo` property.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understand the problem now!

Comment: But how can I access the item without write "value.demo.text"? Can I just write out "value.text"?

Comment: You can't use `value.text` because `text` is not a property of `value`: it's a property of `demo`. If you need access to all the `demo` properties you will need to correct the format of your JSON (a server-side fix), or write a custom JSON parser that understands your particular data format.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is something wrong with your JSON. Try alert codes and make sure the parsed JSON is in the right format, i.e key/value pairs

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ you can check for codes.demo codes.admin etc ...

Comment: yeah it looks like it's null in the console.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use jQuery to parse JSON. Just `var codes = JSON.parse(history)`

```
$.each(codes, function(k, v){
  console.log(v )
});
```

Comment: `$.parseJSON` is more portable, since some old browsers don't have `JSON.parse`. `jQuery` provides its own implementation in that case.